# Joomla Module Positions not available on all pages

Tags: joomla, module

The module positions top works and displays the module on some pages of the site but not all. On the pages that it doesnt display the html just shows the top comment but nothing else.

Is this a bug or has the person who built the template disabled the module position to show on certain pages?

This is the page that it does not display on
http://landscontractingltd.multi-web-services.co.uk/city-living-apartments/15-city-living-apartments

Answer (score 0):

Just had a quick look and I cant see that position on the page you have specified. If it's not available you can add an extra module position by editing the current template code (method varies depending on template).

Tip: you can view all template positions in Joomla 3.x quite easily by following these steps

- Log into your Joomla 3.0 administrative dashboard
- In the top menu, click Extensions and then click Template Manager
- In the tabs at the top of the page, click the Options tab
- Under the Templates tab, find Preview Module Positions > enable
- Once again, in the top menu, click Extensions and then click Template
  Manager
- Now that we have the Preview Module Positions setting enabled, you
  will see a preview icon next to your Site Templates. Click the
  preview icon next to the template you would like to view.

You can also view your module positions by appending tp=1 to the web address - like http://landscontractingltd.multi-web-services.co.uk/city-living-apartments/15-city-living-apartments?tp=1

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply. The top module position is available on other pages. Can you set module positions to be available only on certain pages?

Comment: you sure can, download [this extension](https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/advancedmodulemanager) It allows you full control over your modules, positions, layout and it's free.

Comment: thanks, i was more thinking i wonder how the person who built the template has done that so i can change what they have done.

Comment: It's hard for me to tell without looking at the mvc template structure. Could you contact the template developer and ask them?